# how to i find out how old my locate database is?

Tags: locate

```
locate -Sd /path/to/db
```

does not give the age of the database. And i can't find any further info in the man pages of locate or updatedb.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need locate to find out. Just right-click on the file in Explorer and select Properties. The "Created" value tells you when the database has been created.